# Springboot property binding for Kotlin nested immutable data class not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, controller, immutability

I'm using Springboot 2.2.6. I try to bind controller get query parameters to a complex class with nested member, e.g.

```
data class Test
@ConstructorProperties("name", "nested")
constructor(val name: String?, val nested: Nested?)

data class Nested
@ConstructorProperties("name", "name2")
constructor(val name: String, val name2: String)
```

Basically the property binding works, but not for a nested data class, I get something like this

```
Invalid property 'nested' of bean class [Test]: Could not instantiate property type [Neseted] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Neseted.<init>()
```

Any ideas to get this work? Thank you!

Comment: Is `Nested` annotated as a `@Component`? also what happens when you explicitly use `@Autowired` on the `Nested` primary constructor

Comment: No, these are no Spring beans, its about the controller and property binding via query parameters. The controller method looks something like this:
    @GetMapping
    fun get(test: Test)

Comment: could you provide the passed query parameters?

Comment: They are binded by Spring, what basically does work. If have a query like "...?name=yo", Test.name will be "yo". But it does not work for pathed complex members with e.g. "...?name=yo&nested.name=hey"

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry. As far as I remember I solved it without the binding more directly.